# Run JS function every new minute

Tags: javascript, function, time, updates, timing

So I've got this JavaScript clock I'm working on and I want it to be perfectly synced with the clients' system clock. I know how to get the current time using a `Date` object and I know how to run the update function every 60000 milliseconds (1 minute). The thing is that the client might load the page when half a minute has already passed, making the clock lag behind with 30 seconds. Is there any way to just run the update function when the minute-variable actually changes? (I only want minute-precision.)

How I get the current time:

```
var time = new Date();
var currentHour = time.getHours();
var currentMinute = time.getMinutes();
```

How I run the update function every 60000 ms:

```
setInterval(update,60000); //"update" is the function that is run
```

Comment: Can you show your current code so we can adapt?

Comment: Subtract `60` from the current amount of seconds, run the `timeout` in that time, and every one after that for a minute

Comment: Like this? `var t = time.getSeconds(); setTimeout(function() { setInterval(update, 60000); update(); }, (60-t) * 1000)` *(Thanks tymeJV)*

Comment: @cookiemonster -- `(60 - time.getSeconds()) * 1000` for the remaining time in the minute

Comment: @tymeJV Do you mean I should check the remaining time in the minute each minute? Wouldn't it be enough to do it once and then go to 60000?

Comment: @AxelK - Javascript timers aren't really very accurate, so relying on them to be *perfectly* accurate is a bad idea. Usually the question is how to start the clock based on servertime, as the clients clock can be anything really, and there's no guarantee it's accurate.

Comment: To maintain accuracy, you'll really need to audit things every so often and make adjustments as needed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the user logs in, get the current time and seconds of the minute, subtract `60` to get the remaining seconds, then multiply to set the timer

```
var time = new Date(),
    secondsRemaining = (60 - time.getSeconds()) * 1000;

setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(update, 60000);
}, secondsRemaining);
```

Comment: You're only missing the first invocation. There should be an `update();` call inside the `setTimeout` since `setInterval` will wait the full `60000` before its first invocation.

Comment: Brilliant! You deserve an award!

Comment: Also, I wonder if it should maybe be offset to be late by a second or so, so that it always runs in the new minute. Because the timers aren't perfectly accurate, there may be times where it runs a couple milliseconds early, which would cause the timer to not change until the next minute *(assuming it caught up)*.

Comment: @cookiemonster - in the demo jsFiddle in my answer, I round the time to the nearest minute before displaying so that it would still work even if the timer was 1ms early.  I also have a self-adjusting interval so I don't rely on `setInterval()` staying aligned perfectly and I align with ms precision, not just second precision.  This answer could be off by as much as 999ms for its update time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 9):

First, you have to understand that timers in javascript are not guaranteed to be called on time so therefore you cannot be perfectly synced at all times - javascript just isn't a real-time language like that.  It is single threaded so a timer event has to wait for other javascript that might be executing at the time to finish before a timer can be executed.  So, you must have a design that still does as best as possible even if the timer is delayed (called later than it's supposed to be).

If you wanted to try to stay as close to aligned and do the fewest screen updates and be the most friendly to mobile battery life, I'd suggest this self-aligning code which realigns itself on each tick based on the time remaining until the next minute change:

```
function runClock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeToNextTick = (60 - now.getSeconds()) * 1000 - now.getMilliseconds();
    setTimeout(function() {
        update();
        runClock();
    }, timeToNextTick);
}

// display the initial clock
update();
// start the running clock display that will update right on the minute change
runClock();
```

This has the advantage that it only calls the update once on the next minute boundary.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/u7Hc5/

Comment: I can't get it to work, would you mind providing a jsFiddle :)?

Comment: @AxelK - I had a typo in my code and it wasn't as accurate as it could be.  I've now provided a working demo jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/u7Hc5/

Comment: @AxelK - I should mention that my latest implementation is self aligning to the minute boundary and aligns to within the nearest millisecond.  The other implementations in other answers here align to the nearest second boundary which could be as much as 999ms off.  Obviously, JS timers aren't guaranteed in accuracy, but this has the advantage that if the timer is on-time, this will be more accurate that the other implementations and it will self correct over time.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there a new instance of setTimeout created whenever the runClock function is called? Does this have an effect to the memory?

Comment: @Manolis - there is a new instance of `setTimeout()` created each time `runClock()` is called, but the prior one is done so it can be garbage collected so there should be no build-up of memory.

Comment: Great approach!, this one should be the accepted answer as it is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time = new Date();
var currentHour = time.getHours();
var currentMinute = time.getMinutes();
var currentSecond   =   time.getSeconds();

var updateinterval = setInterval(startTimer,(60-currentSecond)*1000);

function startTimer(){
    clearInterval(updateinterval);
    setInterval(update,60000);
}

function update(){
    var time = new Date();
    console.log(time.getSeconds());
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I would set an interval to run each second, then check if time.getSeconds() == 0. This way you could execute an action whenever a new minute starts, based on the client time.

Comment: You can't just strictly look for `getSeconds() == 0` because you may miss that particular second interval as intervals are not guaranteed to be called perfectly on time in javascript.